# glm fit with iris invalid first argument, must be vector (list or atomic)

Tags: r

I have the following working code

```
glm.fit <- glm(Income ~ .,data=train,family=binomial) 
summary(glm.fit)
```

However there are some questions I want to ask, and so I can ask the questions I decided to try and reproduce the code using the iris data set.

I tried

```
 cf<-iris
 glm.fit(Petal.Width ~ ., cf, family = binomial)
```

but I get an error

> Error in dim(data) <- dim : invalid first argument, must be vector (list or atomic)

[Update]

I see the data I expect using the following

```
library(dplyr)
 cf<-iris
 cf %>% head(10)
```

Comment: can you try `head(cf)` and check it looks like what you think it should?

Comment: `glm.fit` only takes `x` and `y` arguments, not a formula or a `data` argument. Perhaps you want to use `glm`. However, `binomial` is not the correct choice for the continuous outcome `Petal.Width`. Start by reading `?glm`.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question in response to these comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.

First, there's no need to create the variable `cf`. You can just use `iris`.

Second, `glm.fit` takes as its first 2 arguments `x` and `y`. From the documentation, accessible at `?glm.fit`:

> For glm.fit: x is a design matrix of dimension n * p, and y is a vector of observations of length n.

Your first line of code uses `glm` to create a **variable** named `glm.fit` - this is not the same as the function of that name.

If you want to use `glm`, that function can take a formula and the name of a data frame as arguments. So this works:

```
glm(Petal.Width ~ ., data = iris)
```

But this gives an error:

```
glm(Petal.Width ~ ., data = iris, family = binomial)
```

> Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

That's because the response variable, `Petal.Width` is continuous. You use the `binomial` family when the response takes 2 values (yes/no, 0/1, true/false).

Comment: gee, not a great choice for a variable name then.